# WSO2 Integration studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I can't mcv install applications from the source code.
I have a problem because I can't download the application from web site wso2 I wanted to get open source version, but it is only available as source code and I don't know how to install it

```
org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: resource missing at https:
//github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/releases/download/v4.2.0-rc/wso2mi-4.2.0-rc.z
ip, status: 404 Not Found
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWago
n.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1191)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWago
n.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1140)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream (StreamWagon.java:126) 
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer (StreamWagon.java:88)      
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get (StreamWagon.java:61)
    at com.googlecode.download.maven.plugin.internal.WGet.doGet (WGet.java:377) 
    at com.googlecode.download.maven.plugin.internal.WGet.execute (WGet.java:282
)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui
ldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor
.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.
java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
25)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347
)
[WARNING] Retrying (1 more)
Downloading: https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/releases/download/v4.2.0-r
c/wso2mi-4.2.0-rc.zip
org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: resource missing at https:
//github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/releases/download/v4.2.0-rc/wso2mi-4.2.0-rc.z
ip, status: 404 Not Found
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClient
Wagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1191)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClient
Wagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1140)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:12
6)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)   
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at com.googlecode.download.maven.plugin.internal.WGet.doGet(WGet.java:37
7)
        at com.googlecode.download.maven.plugin.internal.WGet.execute(WGet.java:
282)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecu
tor.java:370)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecut
or.java:351)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:171)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:298)       
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)       
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
347)
[WARNING] Could not get content
org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: resource missing at https:
//github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/releases/download/v4.2.0-rc/wso2mi-4.2.0-rc.z
ip, status: 404 Not Found
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWago
n.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1191)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWago
n.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1140)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream (StreamWagon.java:126) 
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer (StreamWagon.java:88)      
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get (StreamWagon.java:61)
    at com.googlecode.download.maven.plugin.internal.WGet.doGet (WGet.java:377) 
    at com.googlecode.download.maven.plugin.internal.WGet.execute (WGet.java:282
)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui
ldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor
.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.
java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
25)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347
)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Reactor Summary for WSO2 Integration Studio - Parent 8.2.0-SNAPSHOT:     
[INFO] 
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio - Parent ................... SUCCESS [  0.292 s] 
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio - Component Parent ......... SUCCESS [  0.019 s] 
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Studio Platform Parent ..... SUCCESS [  0.115 s] 
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Kernel Plugins ............. SUCCESS [  0.029 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio kernel.libraries ................ SUCCESS [  5.672 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Logging Framework ............... SUCCESS [  0.618 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Common Utils .................... SUCCESS [  2.784 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Maven Invoker ................... SUCCESS [  1.687 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Platform Core ................... SUCCESS [  3.374 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Welcome Perspective ............. SUCCESS [  0.869 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Platform UI ..................... SUCCESS [  2.761 s] 
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Plugin Sample .............. SUCCESS [  1.568 s] 
[INFO] Updator Tool ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.651 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Libraries ....................... SUCCESS [  4.473 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Common UI Components ............ SUCCESS [  1.152 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Samples ......................... SUCCESS [  1.265 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Governance Registry Core ........ SUCCESS [  1.915 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Registry Libraries .............. SUCCESS [  1.268 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Cloud Utils ..................... SUCCESS [  0.954 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Remote User Managemenr .......... SUCCESS [  1.689 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Registry Resource Authorization . SUCCESS [  2.915 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Registry Base ................... SUCCESS [  4.472 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Registry Manager Remote ......... SUCCESS [  2.759 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Carbon Application Core ......... SUCCESS [  1.668 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Carbon Application Maven ........ SUCCESS [  1.522 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Carbon Features ................. SUCCESS [  0.490 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Server Base ..................... SUCCESS [  0.640 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Carbon Server Base .............. SUCCESS [  4.126 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Project Extensions .............. SUCCESS [  1.216 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Composite Application Project ... SUCCESS [  3.023 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Composite Application Project Module for WTP Server To
ols SUCCESS [  1.135 s]
[INFO] Integration Studio Carbon Server Model ............. SUCCESS [  1.922 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Remote Carbon Server ............ SUCCESS [  2.157 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Carbon Server 4.0 ............... SUCCESS [  2.182 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Carbon Server 4.2 ............... SUCCESS [  1.774 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Carbon Server 4.4 ............... SUCCESS [  1.724 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Enterprise Integrator (Carbon 4.4 based) SUCCESS [  1.
637 s]
[INFO] Integration Studio Enterprise Integrator (Carbon 4.4 based) SUCCESS [  1.
914 s]
[INFO] Integration Studio Enterprise Integrator (Carbon 4.4 based) SUCCESS [  1.
836 s]
[INFO] Integration Studio Enterprise Integrator (Carbon 4.4 based) SUCCESS [  2.
170 s]
[INFO] Integration Studio General Project ................. SUCCESS [  1.894 s] 
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Server ..................... SUCCESS [  0.143 s] 
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Server Plugins ............. SUCCESS [  0.018 s] 
[INFO] Integration Studio Enterprise Integrator (Carbon 4.4 based) SUCCESS [  4.
867 s]
[INFO] Integration Studio Enterprise Integrator (Carbon 4.4 based) SUCCESS [  3.
151 s]
[INFO] Integration Studio Enterprise Integrator (Carbon 4.4 based) FAILURE [  1.
266 s]
[INFO] Integration Studio Dashboard ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Integration Studio Registry Perspective ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Integration Studio Registry Search ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Integration Studio Registry Manager Local .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Integration Studio Registry Resource Artifact ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Integration Studio Carbon Application Registry Connector SKIPPED
[INFO] Integration Studio Security Project ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Integration Studio Security UI ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Integration Studio Java Library Artifact ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Integration Studio MMM Project ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Integration Studio Web Based UI Components ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Integration Studio Template Dashboard .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Integration Studio Docker Image Creation Porject ... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Tooling - EI Server plugin . SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Platform Features .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Platform Feature ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio ESB Tooling Dependencies. .. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Platform - P2 Repositories . SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Platform - P2 Repository ... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Server Tooling Feature Parent SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Server Feature ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio - Server Tools P2 Repository Parent SKIPPED      
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio - Server P2 Repository ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio ESB Tools .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio ESB Plugins ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Libraries .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio ESB Core ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio ESB Graphical Editor - GMF Core SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Connector Artifact ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Data Service Tools ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Data Service Plugins ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio DS Tree view Model ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio DS Tree Viewer Controller .. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio DS Editor Source ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio DS Tree View ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio DS Artifact ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Datasource Project ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Synapse Unit Testing Framework Utility ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio ESB Project ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio ESB Form Editors ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio ESB Graphical Editor - GMF Persistance SKIPPED   
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio ESB Graphical Editor - GMF Edit SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Endpoint artifact .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Local Entry artifact ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Synapse API Artifact ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio ESB Graphical Editor Diagram SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Visual DataMapper .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Visual DataMapper Edit ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Visual DataMapper Editor ... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Visual DataMapper Diagram .. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Proxy Service artifact ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Proxy Service artifact ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Mediator Project ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Synapse Artifact ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Synapse Task Artifact ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Template artifact .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Message Store Artifact ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Message Processor Artifact . SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Inbound endpoint artifact .. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Visual DataMapper Project .. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Templates Contributor ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] org.wso2.integrationstudio.esb.theme ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Docker Image Generation Utility SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Hybrid Integration Utility . SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio APIM Project ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Endpoint Central ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio API Manager Perspective .... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio ESB Feature ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio ESB Feature ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio - ESB P2 Repository Parent . SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio - ESB P2 Repository ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Eclipse Data Service XML Editor ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Dataservice Custom Validator Creator SKIPPED     
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio DS Artifact Template ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Datasource ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio DS Artifact ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio DS validator Artifact ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Data Service Tooling Feature Parent SKIPPED      
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio Data Service Feature ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio - Data Service P2 Repository Parent SKIPPED      
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio - Data Service P2 Repository SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio - Distribution ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio RCP Product Assembly ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio RCP Plugin ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio RCP Feature ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Integration Studio RCP Product ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time:  27:33 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-29T18:24:24+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin:download-mav
en-plugin:1.3.0:wget (download-mi-runtime) on project org.wso2.integrationstudio
.carbonserver44microei42: IO Error: Could not get content -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal c
om.googlecode.maven-download-plugin:download-maven-plugin:1.3.0:wget (download-m
i-runtime) on project org.wso2.integrationstudio.carbonserver44microei42: IO Err
or
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor
.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.
java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
25)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347
)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: IO Error
    at com.googlecode.download.maven.plugin.internal.WGet.execute (WGet.java:331
)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui
ldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor
.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.
java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
25)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347
)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Could not get content  
    at com.googlecode.download.maven.plugin.internal.WGet.execute (WGet.java:313
)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui
ldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor
.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.
java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
25)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347
)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :org.wso2.integrationstudio.carbonserver44microei42
```

I just want to install integration studio
Already installed micro integrator

Answer (score 0):

It seems WSO2 only allows corporate Email addresses to download the products and tooling now. No idea why they did this and whether there is a workaround for that. You can still Download Integration Studio 8.1 from Github at https://github.com/wso2/integration-studio/releases/tag/v8.1.0

Once downloaded you can update it if needed.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That's the right version! I'm glad!

Comment: @PawelForys Glad it helped. If any of the answers helped you to resolve the issue, please consider marking them as accepted answers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that's correct. Now we only allow corporate emails to download our products from the website. Once you provide a valid corporate email address, you will receive an email with the download link. However, all our products are available on GitHub for you to download. You can download product binaries from GitHUb, build them yourself and run Open Source.

The main reason behind this is, the product you download from website has a different licence - EULA compared to the one you download from GitHub - Apache 2.0. The EULA licence does not allow running our products without a valid subscription. To avoid this confusion, we have restricted the downloads.